# Python to count commas in a text file

Tags: python

I am trying to count the commas between entries in a text file so I can use the number of commas to find the number of entries to come up with the average. Unfortunately it comes up with commacount of zero.

```
file = open("inputs.txt", "r")

    line = file.read()

    commaCount = 0

    for line in file:
        for char in line:
            if char == ',':
                commaCount+=1

    commacount2 = (multiply(commaCount,2))

    total = sum(int(num) for num in line.strip(',').split(','))

    print(commaCount)
    print(commacount2)

    print("Your average for all inputs is" + str(divide(total,commacount2)))
```

Answer (score 5):

You have already consumed the file iterator with `line = file.read()` so you are not iterating over anything. You should forget `read` and iterate over the file object itself:

```
with  open("inputs.txt", "r") as f:
    count = sum(line.count(",") for line in f)
    # f.seek(0)
    # use the lines again
```

If you want to get the pointer back to the start to iterate again you could `f.seek(0)` but I am not sure what the `total = sum(int(num) for num in line.strip(',').split(','))` is doing.

Once you call .read or .readlines you have move the pointer to the end of the file so unless you `f.seek(0)` you cannot iterate over all the lines again, you are basically doing:

```
In [8]: iterator = iter((1,2,3))
In [9]: list(iterator) # consume
Out[9]: [1, 2, 3]   
In [10]: list(iterator) # empty
Out[10]: [] 
In [11]: list(iterator).count(1) 
Out[11]: 0
```

If you have a comma separated file with integers you can use the csv module, the length of the rows will give you the count of how may elements and map the strings to ints and sum all the row values:

```
import csv
with open("inputs.txt") as f:
    r = csv.reader(f) # create rows split on commas
    sm = 0
    com_count = 0
    for row in r:
        com_count += len(row) # "1,2,3"
        sm += sum(map(int,row))
```

It would actually be `sm += sum(map(int,row)) -1` to match the comma count but if you want the number of elements then counting the commas is not the correct approach `"1,2,3".count(",") ==  2` but there are three elements.

Answer (score 2):

This should help you get started, It should give you the number of commas in a text file, If you use a loop you can use it for all the files you have.

```
with open('inputs.txt', 'r') as f:
    numCommas = f.read().count(',')
    print numCommas
```

Comment: Well it works doesn't it? If he needs something better he can use something better but this is a simple way to get the information he asked for. Sure its probably not the best way or most optimized but we are talking about python here, a language not used to be lightweight or fast but to be simple to understand.